# WO2011115992A3 status?

Tags: patentstatut

I would like to know if the patent WO2011115992A3 can be considered as abandonned, quoting for australia country, as their is no answer from the creator to the international report since 7 years.

Furthermore, this patent is too general, it prevents to make anything with 2 layers of bioplastic.

Best regards

Comment: It’s only an application, not a patent. Even with the broader claims of an application, it doesn’t prevent any use of 2 layers of bio plastic.

Answer (score 0):

In US the patent has been granted [US 9,186,868 B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9186868B2/en) and is the only country where a national phase has been filed, there is no National Phase for the patent in Australia.